# Operator inversion to get propagator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, propagator

The propagator $\Delta(p)$ satisfies the relation:

$$\left(p_\mu p_\nu -p^2 g_{\mu\nu}+\frac{n_\mu n_\nu}{\xi}\right)\Delta^{\nu\rho} = i\delta^\nu_\rho.$$

Thus $\Delta(p)$ is obtained by inverting $\left(p_\mu p_\nu -p^2 g_{\mu\nu}+\frac{n_\mu n_\nu}{\xi}\right)$ and multplying it by $i$.

It is known that $\left(p_\mu p_\nu -p^2 g_{\mu\nu}+\frac{n_\mu n_\nu}{\xi}\right)$ and its inverse leaves invariant both the subspace spanned by $p^\mu$ and by $n^\nu$ and its orthogonal complement. What could be the general form of $\Delta(p)$ by this information?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: $\Delta^{\mu\nu}(p)$ has two indices and should be symmetric. You have at your disposal $p_\mu$, $n_\mu$ and $g_{\mu\nu}$. You can therefore suggest a combination of $p_\mu p_\nu$, $p_{(\mu}n_{\nu)}$, $n_\mu n_\nu$ and $g_{\mu\nu}$: $$\Delta^{\mu\nu}(p) = A(p) p^\mu p^\nu + B(p) p^{(\mu}n^{\nu)}+C(p)n^{\mu}n^\nu+gD(p)g^{\mu\nu}.$$ However I confess I'm somewhat confused about the $n_\mu$ in your equation. If this were QED after gauge-fixing the propagator equation is$$\left[\eta^{\mu\alpha}k^2-\left(1-\frac{1}{\xi}\right)k^\mu k^\alpha\right]\Delta_{\alpha\nu}(k)=\delta^\mu_{\phantom\mu\nu}.$$

Answer (score 1):

We have:
\begin{equation}
\left(p_\mu p_\nu-p^2 g_{\mu\nu}+\frac{n_\mu n_\nu}{\xi}\right)p^\nu p^\rho
=\frac{n^\sigma p_\sigma}{\xi}n_\mu p^\rho.
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\left(p_\mu p_\nu-p^2 g_{\mu\nu}+\frac{n_\mu n_\nu}{\xi}\right)n^\nu n^\rho
=(n^\sigma p_\sigma)p_\mu n^\rho+\left(-p^2+\frac{n^2}{\xi}\right)n_\mu n^\rho
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\left(p_\mu p_\nu-p^2 g_{\mu\nu}+\frac{n_\mu n_\nu}{\xi}\right)g^{\nu\rho}
=p_\mu p^\rho-p^2\delta_\mu^\rho+\frac{1}{\xi}n_\mu n^\rho.
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\left(p_\mu p_\nu-p^2 g_{\mu\nu}+\frac{n_\mu n_\nu}{\xi}\right)p^\nu n^\rho
=\frac{n^\sigma p_\sigma}{\xi}n_\mu p^\rho
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\left(p_\mu p_\nu-p^2 g_{\mu\nu}+\frac{n_\mu n_\nu}{\xi}\right)n^\nu p^\rho
=(n^\sigma p_\sigma)p_\mu p^\rho-p^2n_\mu p^\rho+\frac{n^2}{\xi}n_\mu p^\rho
\end{equation}
On the right side, you have the five expressions $\delta_\mu^\rho$ as well as $n_\mu p^\rho$, $p_\mu n^\rho$, $p_\mu p^\rho$ and $n_\mu n^\rho$. A suitable linear combination of $p^\nu p^\rho$, $n^\nu n^\rho$, $g^{\nu\rho}$, $p^\nu n^\rho$ and $n^\nu p^\rho$, the five coefficients obtained by the five resulting linear equations, will give you $\Delta^{\nu\rho}$. Of course the third equations directly yields, that the coefficient before $g^{\nu\rho}$ has to be $-\frac{i}{p^2}$. I think, you can take it from here.